# ViewPager.PageTransformer transforming ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I have been following this tutorial on applying a ViewPager.Transformer to my ViewPager. You will noticed that Chris Basha only wrote a tutorial for 2 fragments in a viewpager - I want to use 3 fragments in my viewpager:

https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4

I just want to move 2 textViews from the right side of my fragment inside my viewpager to the left. There are 3 fragments in my viewpager.

Here is my code:

```
private class TranslationPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <=1) { // [-1,1]

                hello.setTranslationX((float) (-(1-position) * 1.5 * pageWidth));
                howareyou.setTranslationX((float) (-(1-position) * 0.5 * pageWidth));
        }
        else {
            view.setAlpha(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is viewpager's page 1 view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    />

<TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
    android:layout_gravity="right"

    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/howareyou"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: layout]

When I move from page 1 to page 2 and back again, the code above works like a charm. The text moves from right to left and then back again and accelerate at different rate to the viewpager movements.

When I move from page 1 - page 2 -page 3 and then go from page 3 - page 2 - page 1 again, the two textviews do not seem to go back to the original position. In fact the textview that contains the word "Hello" doesn't even get displayed and "How are you?" is no longer aligned right:

[image]

How do I make both textViews go back to its original position when going from page1-2-3 and then page3-2-1?

Comment: hello moves faster the how are you... why are you using (1-position) and not just position ?

Comment: The reason is that I have aligned my textviews to my right so 1-position would move it to my left. Otherwise if I just used position, it would move further right.